# Regex of number inside brackets

Tags: php, regex

I need to get the float number inside brackets..

I tried this `'([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+'`  but it returns the first number like 6 in the first example. 
Also I tried this

```
'/\((\d+)\)/'
```

but it returns 0. 
Please note that I need the extracted number either int or float.

Can u plz help

[image]

Comment: try this - `\([\d.]+\)`

Answer (score 1):

As you need to match bracket also, You need to add `()` in regular expression:

```
$str = 'Serving size 6 pieces (40)';
$str1 = 'Per bar (41.5)';
preg_match('#\(([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)\)#', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);

preg_match('#\(([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)\)#', $str1, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (40)
    [1] => 40
)
Array
(
    [0] => (41.5)
    [1] => 41.5
)
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/BcoIh)

Answer (score 0):

You could escape brackets:

```
$str = 'Serving size 6 pieces (41.5)';
if (preg_match('~\((\d+.?\d*)\)~', $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (41.5)
    [1] => 41.5
)
```

Regex:

```
\(    # open bracket
 (    # capture group
  \d+ # one or more numbers
  .?  # optional dot
  \d* # optional numbers
 )    # end capture group
\)    # close bracket
```

You could also use this to get only one digit after the dot:

```
'~\((\d+.?\d?)\)~'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the brackets

```
preg_match('/\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)/', $search, $matches);
```

explanation

```
\(    escaped bracket to look for
(     open subpattern
\d    a number
+     one or more occurance of the character mentioned
(     open Group
?:    dont save data in a subpattern
\.    escaped Point
\d    a number
+     one or more occurance of the character mentioned
)     close Group
?     one or no occurance of the Group mentioned
)     close subpattern
\)    escaped closingbracket to look for
```

matches numbers like
1,
1.1,
11,
11.11,
111,
111.111 but NOT .1, .

https://regex101.com/r/ei7bIM/1

Answer (score 0):

You could match an opening parenthesis, use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match and then match your value:

[`\(\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\))`](https://regex101.com/r/aHOG2V/1)

That would match:

- `\(` Match (
- `\K` Reset the starting point of the reported match
- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `(?: Non capturing group`

  - `\.\d+` Match a dot and one or more digits
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `(?=` Positive lookahead that asserts what follows is

  - `\)` Match )
- `)` Close posive lookahead

[Demo php](https://3v4l.org/bmhMo)